# Concentric circles R

Tags: r, geometry

I want to create 50 concentric circles. I did it with python but now I want to do this in R. I have tried the symbols function but with no result.  I want my circles to start from x,y coordinates and the radius of each circle to be 3times bigger than the previous.

```
step=1
for(i in seq(1,50,1)){
  symbols (x, y, circles=50, col="grey")
step=step+3
}
```

From this I get one circle as a result.

I am new in programming so it is probably very simple. Should I use a specific package?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The beauty of R is that many things can be vectorized, including the imput to the 'symbols' function. Here's an example for you:

```
#vector of radii
#written in a way that's easily changable
n_circles <- 50
my_circles <- seq(1,by=1,length.out = n_circles)
#generate x and y
x <- rep(1,n_circles)
y <- rep(1, n_circles)

#plot
symbols(x,y,1:n_circles)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! This is very useful and quick to run.

Comment: You're welcome. I gave you the solution here, but please have a look at the code you wrote yourself. You are iterating and not doing anything with I but kept plotting the same thing, and step never got used.

Comment: Nice Pink Floyd vinyle. +1